# Press in random time range?

Tags: autohotkey

I am currently having this code which will press Z every 1.5 seconds after activated by pressing B

```
toggle  := 0
return

b::
        toggle  := !toggle
        if (toggle = 1)
                SetTimer, Pressz, 1500
        else
                SetTimer, Pressz, Off
return

Pressz:
        SendInput, z

v::SetTimer, Pressz, 1500
```

But then I am not sure how to change the SetTimer into random time between 0 to 1500

Please help thanks.

Comment: See `Random` [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Random.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing the 'Random' function that 0x464e mentioned, and single fire SetTimer routines, I created this

```
toggle  := 0
return

b::
    toggle  := !toggle
    ;MsgBox %toggle%
    if (toggle){
        gosub Routine
        }
return

Routine:
    if(toggle){
        Random, var, -1500, 0
        gosub Pressz
        SetTimer, Routine, %var%
    }
return

Pressz:
        SendInput, z
return

v::
toggle=1
gosub Routine
return
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer. If it didn't, please let me know how I could improve the answer to solve your problem. @PeanutJams